# Exception while making http request using LWUIT IO and J2me Library

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I have made a method to make http request using LWUIT IO library and also tried with J2me library. Everything is working fine on simulator but when i tired on two different Nokia phones then i have received exception. Both are showing different exceptions. 
Exceptions-

1. 411 length required
2. java.io.IOException: Error in HTTP operation:Error in HTTP operation

Here is my code-

```
  private void startReq(String url) {
    NetworkManager.getInstance().start();
    ConnectionRequest myRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {
    protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            int ch;
            while ((ch = input.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuffer.append((char) ch);
            }
            System.out.println("Response:"+stringBuffer.toString());

        }
    };

    progress = new Progress("Please Wait ", myRequest,true);
    progress.setDisposeOnCompletion(true);


    myRequest.setUrl(url);
    myRequest.setPost(true);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(myRequest);
    progress.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution , it was problem related to Mobile Access Point. I could not recognize the problem because internet was working in browser very fine. so i could not guess that the reason can be Access Point. The problem was solved but still i am not satisfied and also surprised that how all applications were able to access internet service instead my Midlet.

[Check this link to change access point settings](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Blogs/index.php?op=ViewArticle&blogId=32927&articleId=282)

and if somebody knows the reason of this behavior kindly clear my doubt.